# Control Elements in XML c# Serialization

Tags: c#, .net, xml, inheritance, serialization

Folks,

I am trying to create a base class with elements that will exist across several different class types. I am close to the solution but i need a bit more control over the output from XML Serializer class.

UPDATE

---

Ok based on the answer below i have added the Serializable interface for XMl and have got a bit further.

Listed below is the output from my new test APP, the first two XML output as i expect, the third is close but it lacks the namespace at the root element and i need SomeNewNameForPData to act as if it were PData, ie no PData evident as in the last XML shown, and its also missing the Application from the Base Request Class. See final example for expected output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Payment1 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Application="MyApp">
  <Pdata Language="en">
    <TimeStamp>2016-06-17T15:31:37.7767381+01:00</TimeStamp>
  </Pdata>
  <RequestType>Pay1</RequestType>
</Payment1>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Payment2 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Application="MyApp">
  <Sender>ProgramClass</Sender>
  <RequestType>Pay2</RequestType>
</Payment2>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Payment3>
  <SomeNewNameForPData>
    <P_Data Language="en">
      <TimeStamp>2016-06-17T15:31:37.7767381+01:00</TimeStamp>
    </P_Data>
  </SomeNewNameForPData>
</Payment3>
```

Expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Payment3 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Application="MyApp">
  <SomeNewNameForPData Language="en">
      <TimeStamp>2016-06-17T15:31:37.7767381+01:00</TimeStamp>
  </SomeNewNameForPData>
</Payment3>
```

Updated Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Request cp = new Payment1() { Application = "MyApp", DataField = new P_Data() { Language = "en" } };

            Request cp2 = new Payment2() { Application = "MyApp", Sender = "ProgramClass" };

            Request cp3 = new Payment3() { Application = "MyApp", DataField = new P_Data() { Language = "en" } };

            string s1 = cp.MessageAsString();

            string s2 = cp2.MessageAsString();

            string s3 = cp3.MessageAsString();

            Console.WriteLine(s1);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine(s2);
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine(s3);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Helpers : StringWriter
    {
        public override Encoding Encoding
        {
            get { return Encoding.UTF8; }
        }
    }

    public abstract class Request
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string Application { get; set; }

        public virtual string MessageAsString()
        {
            return CreateMessage();
        }

        private string CreateMessage()
        {
            return SerializeObject<Request>(this, null);
        }

        public static string SerializeObject<X>(X toSerialize, XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlNameSpace)
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(toSerialize.GetType());
            StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter();

            string utf8 = ""; ;
            using (StringWriter writer = new Helpers())
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, toSerialize, xmlNameSpace);
                utf8 = writer.ToString();
            }

            return utf8;
        }

    }

    public abstract class RequestType1 : Request
    {
        public RequestType1()
        {
        }

        [XmlIgnore()]
        public abstract string RequestType { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Pdata")]
        public virtual P_Data DataField { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class RequestType2 : Request
    {
        public RequestType2()
        {
        }

        [XmlIgnore()]
        public abstract string RequestType { get; set; }

        public string Sender { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public abstract class RequestType3 : RequestType1, IXmlSerializable
    {
        public RequestType3()
        {
        }

        [XmlElement("SomeNewNameForPData")]
        public override P_Data DataField { get; set; }

        public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteStartElement("SomeNewNameForPData");

            var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("", "");
            new XmlSerializer(typeof(P_Data)).Serialize(writer, this.DataField, ns);

            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }

    public class Payment1 : RequestType1
    {
        public Payment1()
        {
        }

        public override string RequestType
        {
            get
            {
                return "Pay1";
            }
            set { }

        }
    }

    public class Payment2 : RequestType2
    {
        public Payment2()
        {
        }

        public override string RequestType
        {
            get
            {
                return "Pay2";
            }
            set { }

        }
    }

    public class Payment3 : RequestType3
    {
        public Payment3()
        {
        }

        public override string RequestType
        {
            get
            {
                return "Pay3";
            }
            set { }

        }
    }

    public class P_Data
    {
        public P_Data()
        {
            //We need to format the datetime field
            TimeStamp = DateTime.Now;
        }

        [XmlAttribute, DefaultValue("")]
        public string Language { get; set; }

        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So my questions are:

1. How to add or preserve the namespace at the root element for Payment3 when using the custom WriteXml method, do i need to also provide the means to write the base class items or do i not get these by virtue of the fact that i am serializing the class using the XmlSerializer based on its type?
2. I need SomeNewNameForPData to act as if it were PData, ie no PData evident
3. Add back in the Application from the Base Request Class.

TIA

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to display the `<Nodes>` node?

Comment: I am using Nodes as a placholder for the may different claases that can exist in a Request or RequestType2, so this list of NODEs is added to with different classes depending on what is required by the 3rd party. In the Nodes class i specify all the elements that can exist, this is just a subset of them for demo purposes to explain the issue

Answer (score 1):

if you implement the ISerializable interface on your class you can control how the serialization happens. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks Paul, I have implemented the IXMLSerializable interface, i have got further but still some problems remain. I have updated my original post, any further suggestions? TIA

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get is:

```
<MyRequestName Sender="MyAppName" IP="123.456.7.0">
  <NodeWhatever>
    <BaseElement type="SomeData" LanguageCode="en" />
    <BaseElement type="SomeOtherData" Amount="1000" />
  </NodeWhatever>
</MyRequestName>
```

Why? because if you had more than one node there wouldn't be a way to to recreate the original object because there is no way to find out which base element belongs to which node!

```
public abstract class Root
{

    public string Sender { get; set; }


    public string IP { get; set; }

    [Persist("", ChildName = "NodeWhatever")]
    public List<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
}

[PersistInclude(typeof(SomeData),typeof(SomeOtherData))]
public class Node
{
    [Persist("")]
    public List<BaseElement> Elements { get; set; }
}

XmlArchive serial = new XmlArchive(R.GetType());
Archive.ClassKwd = "type";

string utf8 = ""; ;

using (var mm = new MemoryStream())
{
    serial.Write(mm,R,"MyRequestName");
    mm.Position = 0;

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(mm))
    {
        utf8 = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }   
}

Console.WriteLine(utf8);
```

With your updated question I can get this xml , not sure if this is what you want:

```
<Payment1 RequestType="Pay1" Application="MyApp">
  <DataField Language="en" TimeStamp="06/17/2016 10:38:39" />
</Payment1>

<Payment2 RequestType="Pay2" Sender="ProgramClass" Application="MyApp" />

<Payment3 RequestType="Pay3" Application="MyApp">
  <MyNameWhatever Language="en" TimeStamp="06/17/2016 10:38:39" />
</Payment3>
```

Code:

```
public abstract class Request
{
    public string Application { get; set; }

    public virtual string MessageAsString()
    {
        return CreateMessage();
    }

    private string CreateMessage()
    {
        return SerializeObject<Request>(this);
    }

    public static string SerializeObject<X>(X toSerialize)
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlArchive(toSerialize.GetType());
        Archive.Provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        string utf8 = ""; ;
        using (var  writer = new MemoryStream())
        {
            xmlSerializer.Write(writer, toSerialize);
            writer.Position = 0;

            var reader = new StreamReader(writer);
            utf8 = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return utf8;
    }

}

public abstract class RequestType1 : Request
{
    public abstract string RequestType { get; set; }   
    public virtual P_Data DataField { get; set; }
}

public abstract class RequestType2 : Request
{        
    public abstract string RequestType { get; set; }
    public string Sender { get; set; }
}


public abstract class RequestType3 : RequestType1
{
    [Persist("MyNameWhatever")]
    public override P_Data DataField { get; set; }

}

public class Payment1 : RequestType1
{
    public override string RequestType
    {
        get { return "Pay1"; }
        set { }
    }
}

public class Payment2 : RequestType2
{
    public override string RequestType
    {
        get { return "Pay2"; }
        set { }
    }
}

public class Payment3 : RequestType3
{
    public override string RequestType
    {
        get { return "Pay3"; }
        set { }
    }
}

public class P_Data
{
    public P_Data() { TimeStamp = DateTime.Now; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks elios, i have since gone about it a different way based on similar comments i had read elsewhere, i have updated the original post with new code.